# Spring Redis Om error "no such index" when doing a FindBy

Tags: java, spring, redis

I started using Redis Om with spring to store a Json entity.
At the begining of my application I need to query by Id, but this query fails when there are no documents saved already.
I get the error "Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: com.gfa.redis.model.PositionIdx: no such index"

Here is my entity:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document
public class Position {
    @Id
    private  String tradingStrategyId;

    @Indexed
    @NonNull
    private String triggerId;

    @Indexed
    private int tradeId;

    @Indexed
    @NonNull
    private  String symbol;

    @NonNull
    private IntervalEnum interval;

    @NonNull
    private Num pricePerAsset;

    @Indexed
    @NonNull
    private TradeType tradeType;

    @Indexed
    @NonNull
    private OrderType orderType;

    @NonNull
    private Long tradeTime;

    @NonNull
    private Long openKlineTimestamp;
```

and this is the Repo code:

```
@Repository
public interface LiveStrategyRepository  extends RedisDocumentRepository<Position, String> {

    Position findByTradingStrategyId(String tradingStrategyId);

    Position findByTriggerId(String triggerId);

}
```

Finally I enable the document with @EnableRedisDocumentRepositories

The starting flow of the code is to call findByTradingStrategyId("123") to get either a null or the Position stored. Since I have not saved any position yet, I would expect to get a Null. However I get the error.

I guess the issue is that the Index for Position entity is not created, but I have not found a way to create it at startup. Any ideas?

Comment: I am able to catch the exception, so at least I am unblock. Is there a simpler way to get null in case the id I am trying to find does not exist?

Comment: Also, fields like `TradeType` and `OrderType ` are likely causing the issue. You can only indexed basic types. There should be some output on startup that will complain and saying something like "Skipping index creation because...."

Comment: Doesnt seem to even try to initialize the index. these are all logs I get: Bootstrapping Spring Data RedisJSON repositories in DEFAULT mode. Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 74 ms. Found 1 RedisJSON repository interface.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the index is not getting created, can you launch the redis-cli and do a:

```
ft._list
```

That should show the list of indices in the system. Also, what distribution of Redis are you running. Redis OM works with Redis Stack which has a search engine and extra datatypes like JSON.

If you're stuck stop by the Redis Discord server and I can help you there in more depth.

Comment: ft._list returns empty. I use Redis stack for saving the JSON objects. Adding objects is not a problem. Retrieving them is causing me an exception every time.

Comment: So I monitored the activity and at no point is the index created when I launch the application. Can I Make the Spring app create the index if non existant?

Comment: Comment out the `@Indexed` annotation on `tradeType` and `orderType` restart the app and see if the index gets created now.

Comment: It was not fixed. I created a simple Entity with a String and id and its own repository. On Startup, checking Redis logs, I dont get any Index creation from the app. Is there an additional configuration that needs to be added?

Comment: I get these logs from Spring: RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data RedisJSON repositories in DEFAULT mode.
RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 80 ms. Found 2 RedisJSON repository interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. I think the redis Om for Spring is a bit broken, but that later.

First Finding:
My entity definition was looking for index ".<entity_class_name>Idx". For some reason The whole startup and setup is not creating the index automatically (not sure if that is one of the problems).

I tried to change the Index of the document by passing Arguments to the annotation like:

```
@Document(value = "PositionIdx", prefixes = {"com", "gfa", "redis", "model", "Position"})
```

But the index searched for was still the same.

I had to mannually create the index myself with redis_cli and FT.CREATE

Once that was created, the original exception of index not found was resolved.

Then, the second problem: no documents were returned. I was searching for tradingStrategyId that was indexed using the @Indexed annotation in the Entity:

```
@NonNull
@Indexed
private  String tradingStrategyId;
```

For some reason, the actual query performed in Redis was:

```
"FT.SEARCH" "com.gfa.redis.model.PositionIdx" "@tradingStrategyId:{emaCross1}" "LIMIT" "0" "10000"
```

This returned a 0 match.
Checking online for examples, I saw the query should be using parentheses, so running this in the cli returned matches:

```
 ft.search com.gfa.redis.model.PositionIdx '@tradingStrategyId:(emaCross1)' LIMIT "0" "1000"
```

Notice "@tradingStrategyId:{emaCross1}" changed to '@tradingStrategyId:(emaCross1)'
Apparently the JPA was treating my String as some other type, thus finding no match.
When I changed the Annotation to @TextIndexed it worked.

I guess the @Indexed annotation is broken for inferring the actual type.

I am still trying to figure out how to auto create the index if not existant, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welp, I think I find the actual issue: I was running my code ContextRefreshedEvent for Spring. I think my Redis JPA was not setting things up before I tried to execute everything. So I never had an index because that logic was way after!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the final solution for reference.

I was executing my logic inside an ApplicationListener event for Spring for ContextRefreshedEvent. This event is raised once the initial configuration of beans is set up and before the actual app start.

I did not know that Redis Om document is not set up in this lifecycle part, but until the application start. Once the application starts the setup of Indexes happens automatically.

Since I was executing my code before that, for testing, the indexes were not created and the whole redis repository seemed faulty. I changed the Event listener to ApplicationStartedEvent which will let Redis JPA setup correctly.

The issue is fixed.